# Validating a function that only measure a subset of the measurable sapce being measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega = \{ a, b, c\}$ with sigma algebra $ \mathcal{F} = \{ \emptyset, \{a,b\}, \{c\}, \Omega \}$ where {a, b, c} are distinct elements

Consider a function
$$\mu : \Omega \rightarrow R$$
$$\mu(\omega) = 1 \  if \  \omega \in \{a, b\}$$

So
$$ \mu^{-1}(B) = 
\begin{cases} 
\{a, b\} & \text{if} \ 1 \in B\\
\{\emptyset\} & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases} $$

1. According to the definition of measurable function, I want to confirm that $\mu$ is measurable w.r.p.t $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{B}(R)$ right? since the inverse of $\mu$ are elements of sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$
2. Would it be possible that a function in a measurable space is considered only measurable w.r.p.t. a certain sigma algebra but is not measurable w.r.p.t. other sigma algebras of the same measurable space?

Comment: What is $\mu(c)$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, this is my question, do I have to define $\mu(c)$ or otherwise it will be ill-defined?

Comment: The statement $\mu:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ means that $\mu(x)\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $x\in\Omega$ so this implies that $\mu(c)$ is well defined.

Comment: Well, if you want to write down a correct expression for $\mu^{-1}(B)$ you need to think about  $\mu(c)$. It’s true that $\mu$ is measurable regardless of the particular value it takes.

Comment: @DerekH., I see, so if I state $\mu :\Omega \rightarrow R$ then my $\mu(c)$ needs to be specified. What if I change the statement to $\mu: \omega \rightarrow R$ where $\omega \in \{a,b\}$? I mean is this even 'legal' ?

Comment: If this change is made then for $\mu$ to be measurable we need to consider instead a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega'=\{a,b\}$ rather than on $\Omega$, since $\mathcal{F}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega'$.

Comment: @DerekH. Thanks for the explanation, I understand it now

Answer (score 2):

1. For a function $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to be measurable in $\mathcal{F}$ in the sense you describe, it is necessary and sufficient to verify that $f^{-1}(Y)\in\mathcal{F}$ for any open set $Y\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Note: I don't believe your expression for $\mu^{-1}(B)$ is correct, since taking $B=\mathbb{R}$ gives $\mu^{-1}(B)=\Omega$.

2. Yes, for instance if we define $f(a)=1$ and $f(b)=f(c)=0$ then $f^{-1}((\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}))=\{a\}\notin\mathcal{F}$ so $f$ is not measurable with resepect to $\mathcal{F}$, but if we define $\mathfrak{M}=\mathbb{P}(\Omega)$ then $f$ is measurable with respect to $\mathfrak{M}$.